# dropdown do PrimeNG não carrega

Tags: angular

Eu acho que meu problema é na pagina HTML no meu projeto Angula, não posso deixar de salientar que estou usando a lib do PrimeNG.

Veja a figura abaixo, está carregando perfeitamente a minha lista;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém mesmo assim não consigo carregar minha lista no componente do **dropdown** do PrimeNG

Esse aqui é meu HTML;

```
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <mt-input-container  label="Categorias">
                <p-dropdown [options]="menu.restaurantId"
 name="restaurantId"  placeholder="Selecione"
                [(ngModel)]="menu.restaurantId"
                ></p-dropdown>

            </mt-input-container>
          </div>
```

A lista é carregada por esse método.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategorias();
  }

  getCategorias() {
    this.menuAdminService.categoriasMenu().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response.menu)
        if (!response.menu) {

        } else {
          this.menus = response.menu.map( c =>(
            { label: c.name, value: c._id }
          ))
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

=====================================ATUALIZAÇÃO

Eu fiz essa alteração no HTML

```
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <mt-input-container  label="Categorias">
            <p-dropdown [options]="menus" name="restaurantId"  placeholder="Selecione"
            [(ngModel)]="menus"
            ></p-dropdown>

        </mt-input-container>
      </div>
```

Ele está carregando a lista, só não está mostrando como na imagem a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que vc esqueceu do optionLabel:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="menus" name="restaurantId"
    optionLabel="name" placeholder="Selecione" [(ngModel)]="menus"
  ></p-dropdown>
```